# Display free shipping threshold based on Woocommerce min amount order from shipping settings

Tags: woocommerce

I want to display shipping notice based on free shipping settings for min amount order. I have more then one shipping zone based on different country and currency. Tried to use the following code, it works when you add product to cart, the shipping notice is display but as if you update quantity the shipping notice is removed, maybe duo to Ajax load? Can I add something to this code to make it work with qty update on product?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents', 'display_free_shipping_cart_notice_zones' );
    function display_free_shipping_cart_notice_zones() {
     
    // Get Shipping Methods for Current Zone
     
    global $woocommerce;
    $shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->get_shipping_methods();
     
    // Loop through the array to find min_amount value/s
     
    foreach($shipping_methods as $key => $value) {
        if ( $shipping_methods[$key]->min_amount > 0 ) {
          $min_amounts[$key] = $shipping_methods[$key]->min_amount;
        }
    }
    if ( is_array($min_amounts) ) {
    // Find lowest min_amount
     
    $min_amount = min($min_amounts);
     
    // Get Cart Subtotal inc. Tax excl. Shipping
     
    $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
     
    // If Subtotal < Min Amount Echo Notice
    // and add "Continue Shopping" button
    
        
       if ( $current < $min_amounts ) {
          $added_text = 'Get free shipping if you order ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' more!';
          $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
          $notice = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), 'Continue Shopping', $added_text );
          wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
       }
    
       else if ( $current = $min_amounts ) {
          $added_text = 'Congratulations - Your shipping is now on us and absolutely free :)';
          $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
          //$notice = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), 'Continue Shopping', $added_text );
          $notice = sprintf( '%s', $added_text );
          wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
       }
     }
    }
```